# How do I find the joint probability distribution of three variables?

Tags: probability, covariance

I have three different probability distributions X, Y, and Z, all with a range of {0, 4} and I was able to find their own probability distributions, expected values, and variances.

I'm confused how to find the joint probability distribution of (X, Y, Z) and the joint pmf s.t. f(x, y, z) = P[X = x, Y = y, Z = z]. As well as getting the covariance of each (Cov(X, Y), Cov(Y, Z) and Cov(X, Z)).

Can someone help me with guidance through this?

Comment: Are these variables independent? Otherwise you don't have enough info.

Comment: the variables are not independent

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question.